# Split multi-page tiff with python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

What's the best way to split a multi-page TIFF with python? PIL doesn't seem to have support for multi-page images, and I haven't found an exact port for libtiff for python.  Would PyLibTiff be the way to go?  Can somebody provide a simple example of how I could parse multiple pages within a TIFF?

Comment: PIL has limited support to "multi-image" documents - it cana t least laod, and leat you deal with, individual frames in animated GIFs - I don't know if the TIFF loading plug-in allows you to read each page, though. Can you post a link to one of your tiffs?

Comment: Unfortunately no... The material I'm dealing with right now is sensitive, and I have no clue as to how to generate a generic multi-page tiff from scratch.  I've tried exporting multiple layers in gimp to no avail.  Do you have any code examples?  I could try them out on my machine.

Comment: You might try Python Wand. It is built upon ImageMagick, which can do the separation.

Comment: Hello, I had the same problem and wrote this module to operate with multipage tiff
https://github.com/mpascucci/multipagetiff
You can open the multipage tiff and save pages one by one... if you really want to do it in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do use ImageMagick as external program to convert multi-page fax into viewable PNGs:

```
/usr/bin/convert /var/voip/fax/out/2012/04/fax_out_L1_17.tiff[0] -scale 50x100% -depth 16 /tmp/fax_images/fax_out_L1_17-0-m.png
```

does convert first page to PNG

aaa.tiff[1] would be second page, and so on.

Or to extract all images, do:

```
convert -verbose fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff a.png
fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff[0] TIFF 1728x1078 1728x1078+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 109KiB 0.030u 0:00.030
fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff[1] TIFF 1728x1078 1728x1078+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 109KiB 0.020u 0:00.010
fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff[2] TIFF 1728x1078 1728x1078+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 109KiB 0.020u 0:00.010
fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff=>a-0.png[0] TIFF 1728x1078 1728x1078+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 12KiB 0.030u 0:00.019
fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff=>a-1.png[1] TIFF 1728x1078 1728x1078+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 8KiB 0.040u 0:00.039
fax_in_L1-1333564876.469.tiff=>a-2.png[2] TIFF 1728x1078 1728x1078+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 32KiB 0.070u 0:00.070
```

So, to just split one multi-page TIFF into many-page TIFF you would have to execute:

```
convert in-12345.tiff /tmp/out-12345.tiff
```

and then work with temporary files: /tmp/out-12345-*.tiff

However ImageMagick can do a lot of processing, so you can probably achieve your desired result in one command.

Answer (score 10):

A project (disclosure: which I am one of the main authors, this question was one of the things that prompted me to work on it) which makes this is easy is [PIMS](http://github.com/soft-matter/pims).  The core of PIMS is essentially a cleaned up and generalized version of the following class.

A class to do basic frame extraction + simple iteration.

```
import PIL.Image
class Stack_wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self,fname):
        '''fname is the full path '''
        self.im  = PIL.Image.open(fname)

        self.im.seek(0)
        # get image dimensions from the meta data the order is flipped
        # due to row major v col major ordering in tiffs and numpy
        self.im_sz = [self.im.tag[0x101][0],
                      self.im.tag[0x100][0]]
        self.cur = self.im.tell()

    def get_frame(self,j):
        '''Extracts the jth frame from the image sequence.
        if the frame does not exist return None'''
        try:
            self.im.seek(j)
        except EOFError:
            return None

        self.cur = self.im.tell()
        return np.reshape(self.im.getdata(),self.im_sz)
    def __iter__(self):
        self.im.seek(0)
        self.old = self.cur
        self.cur = self.im.tell()
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            self.im.seek(self.cur)
            self.cur = self.im.tell()+1
        except EOFError:
            self.im.seek(self.old)
            self.cur = self.im.tell()
            raise StopIteration
        return np.reshape(self.im.getdata(),self.im_sz)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the numpy reshaping?

Comment: @speedplane Because `getdata` returns a flattened iterable of the image http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.getdata

Comment: @tacaswell Is there a way to convert extracted frame to png or jpeg files after 'get_frame()' is done?

Comment: @comproch `PIL.Image.fromarray(stack_wrapper_instance.get_frame(i)).save('name.png')`

Answer (score 8):

Imagemagick worked for me real good. Wnen splitting a tiff file, basically converting from tiff to tiff, one can use a flag to force saving output files to individual tiff files. To do that, try

```
convert input.tif output-%d.tif
```

The %d operator is a C-Printf style %d. So, if you need a 3 field running sequence, you can say

```
convert input.tif output-%3d.tif
```

and so on.. %d is replaced by "scene" number of the image. Now, scene numbers may or may not always start with 0 (or 1, if you want it that way). To setup a sequence the way you want, try

```
convert input.tif -scene 1 output-%3d.tif
```

This would start the sequence right from the count you provided.

```
convert -scene 1 input.TIF output-%d.TIF
output-1.TIF
output-2.TIF
output-3.TIF
```

Magick indeed!! :)

[This link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#scene) to documentation has more details. This works on my windows machine too.

Answer (score 3):

The following splits a tif file with multiple frames into tif files where each file is one frame.

```
def parse_tif(filePath):
    img = Image.open(filePath)
    for i in range (numFramesPerTif):
        try:
            img.seek(i)
            img.save('Block_%s.tif'%(i,))
        except EOFError: #end of file error
```

Comment: numFramesPerTif - how do I calculate it? It's currently undefined.

Comment: It's the number of images inside the multi-image tiff file. I don't know how to determine that though

Comment: numFramesPerTif = img.n_frames

Answer (score 0):

After installing [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.8-46-Q16-x64-dll.exe) in Windows. Try the following below in Command Prompt

**1. Test ImageMagick tif file convertion**

```
magick convert input.tif out.tif
```

**2. Convert one multi page tif file to multiple files**

```
magick convert -verbose input.tif otput.png
```

Answer (score -2):

You could convert it to PDF and use pyPDF to split the pages

Comment: I rather not convert to PDF, split, and convert back to TIFF unless there is absolutely no other way to split multi-page TIFFs.  It seems like a backwards way of extracting individual pages, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong...