# PIL(low) and multi-page TIFFS

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

This should be relatively easy, but who knows...

Is there a way to retrieve the number of frames in a multi-page TIFF file using PIL/Pillow, without iterating through the whole stack until `seek` raises an error?

Comment: TIFF file pages are arranged as a linked-list. To count the number of pages in a standard file, you must traverse all of the pages one by one. The only way to avoid it is to add a custom tag to the first page with the number and offsets of the pages.

Comment: Some software writes the number of pages in the standard [PageNumber](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/pagenumber.html) tag. The ImageDescription tag might also contain references to the number of pages in the file (e.g. ImageJ files).

Comment: I just checked: the images I'm working with do not have PageNumber set (rather, it is set to 0).  I guess I'll have to just brute-force it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `n_frames`:

```
from PIL import Image

tiffstack = Image.open('my_img.tiff')
tiffstack.load()

print(tiffstack.n_frames)
```

Comment: Well, I PR'd this myself into pillow (https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1195) but sure, I'll accept the answer :)