# Splitting of TIF file from and to specific pages in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

Splitting of TIF file from and to specific pages in python

I am able to split multipage TIF file into pages sequential and create TIF file for each page using following python code suggested at [Split .TIF file using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340740/split-tif-file-using-pil)
from PIL import Image

```
img = Image.open('multipage.tif')
for i in range(4):
    try:
        img.seek(i)
        img.save('page_%s.tif'%(i,))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

My requirement is to split multipage.tif based on start and end page numbers and save it as different tif file. Eg. Create a file from page #3 to page #5 of  multipage.tif. Can anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('multipage.tif')
frames = []
for i in range(2, 5):
    img.seek(i)
    frames.append(img.copy())
frames[0].save('output.tif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])
```