# Conversion of Multi page .TIF image file into PDF format using Python or Node.js on Windows platform

Tags: python, node.js, image-processing, ocr

I have one multi page `.tiff` image file and I want to convert it into PDF format for further processing.

The idea is to extract information under the any table of TIFF file after converting image into PDF.

How to process the `.tiff` file to convert into PDF on Windows platform using Python or Node.js?

Comment: Will Online conversion works for u ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Constraint is to convert using only python and nodejs offline without using any online services or api.

Comment: Have u looked pypdfocr. it can do the job for u

Comment: Consider this as a starting point: [split-multi-page-tiff-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627652/split-multi-page-tiff-with-python?rq=1)